# Android Emulator: can't connect to server

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm newbie in Android development so forgive me for a banal question

I'm in this situation: I have a server locate on IP address 192.168.11.188; this server sends a JMS message by using MQTT protocol
On my laptop I'm using paho as MQTT messages consumer

I'm building an Android app and I test it by using the emulator

I have the following problem: if i test everything in local by configuring the APP to connect to the JMS server on my laptop and specifying the IP address 10.0.2.2 all works pretty good

When i configure the APP in order to connect to the server on IP address 192.168.11.188 it can't connect (I tried by using telnet and I can confirm that server is alive and active)

Moreover in the sent MQTT message I have a URL that points to a my site. The URL is like: http://192.168.11.188:8080/.....
Well inside the emulator i can't open the URL; I get the error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" (but I'm sure the server is active)
I attach an image showing the error [image: Emulator Error]

I'm struggling on this problem from some days...

I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't figure what I'm missing
How can I configure correctly the emulator in order to connect to the server on the the IP 192.168.11.188 and open web pages always from this IP?

thank you
Angelo

Comment: I know I shouldn't ask.. but I really can't figure out from this issue... How can I solve it?